# To align all buttons equally in relative layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

### Below is a simple code where i am trying to align all the button views

- *How to make sure all the button acquire equal space , as in the figure we can see location and photos button are are not clearly
  spaced*
- I also tried with random textsize its not working :(

**Any ideas**

**What I have tried::**

```
<TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2sp" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/BottomNavigationBarCopperChimneyDesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/CopperChimneyDescriptionButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/CopperChimneyLocationButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/CopperChimneyDescriptionButton"
                    android:text="Location"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/CopperChimneyPhotosButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/CopperChimneyFriendsButton"
                    android:text="Photos"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/CopperChimneyFriendsButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:text="Friends"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>
```

---

[image: FIG]

---

Comment: Have you looked at LinearLayouts with layout_weight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative approach, maybe could be useful sometimes. Solution with LinearLayout and weights works fine, but I don't like extra layout inflates that could be avoided easily, because of performance issues.

**1. Define button width in dimens.xml. Android phones have screen width 320 or 360dp:**

values/dimen.xml

```
<dimen name="button_width">80dp</dimen>
```

values-sw360dp/dimen.xml (these resources will be used for screens 360dp width and more)

```
<dimen name="button_width">90dp</dimen>
```

Of course, you should define extra dimens.xml if tablet support needed.

**2. Use this value for buttons:**

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a LineaLayout if you want equal sizes. You can just put it inside of your RelativeLayout. You also need to give the buttons equal weight. Like here: [Equal buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721087/make-buttons-have-the-same-width-in-layout)